# Solve $z^4 +4z^2 +16 = 0$ over $\Bbb C$

Tags: complex-numbers, quadratics

> Solve the complex number equation $$z^4 +4z^2 +16 = 0$$

---

Using the quadratic formula

$$ z^2 = \frac{-4 \pm \sqrt{4^2 -4(16)}}{2} = -2 \pm 2\sqrt{3} i $$

My teacher proceeded to write:

$$z = 2e^{(\pm \frac{2\pi}{3} +2k \pi)i/2}, \qquad k = 0,1$$

What does this last expression mean in solving for this question?

Comment: You have shown that if $z^4 +4z^2 +16 = 0$, then $z^2=-2 \pm 2\sqrt{3} i.$ You have not calculated $z$, as your teacher did.

Answer (score 2):

In general, the solution to

$$z^2 = r \times e^{i\theta} ~: ~r \in \Bbb{R^+}, ~\theta \in \Bbb{R}$$ is given by

$$z = \sqrt{r} \times e^{i\alpha} ~: \alpha \in 
\left\{\frac{\theta}{2}, ~\frac{\theta + \pi}{2} \right\}.$$

So,

$$-2 \pm \left[i \times 2\sqrt{3}\right]$$

may be re-written as

$$4 \times \left[-\frac{1}{2} \pm i\frac{\sqrt{3}}{2}\right]$$

$$= 4 \times [\cos(\theta) + i\sin(\theta)] = 4e^{i\theta} ~: ~\theta \in \left\{ \frac{2\pi}{3}, ~-\frac{2\pi}{3} \right\}.$$

Simply apply the result directly above to the analysis at the start of this answer.